# Postpositive adjectives

Tags: adjectives, phrase-usage

I know that there are a few cases where we can use the adjective after the noun, which is called postpositive. Here are some examples:

> ***Attorney General*** / ***Secretary General*** / ***court martial***

But I have noticed that some people generalize such a use outside its original idiomatic use. For example:

> The ***Directorate General*** of Democracy offers help to most European societies.

I am wondering why they didn't use ***General Directorate*.**

Comment: Maybe because it's a European and not a British title? In French, it's "la direction générale de la démocratie."

Comment: @Peter Shore: You're right, but for a British or an American native, which is more common: The Directorate General...or The General Directorate...?

Comment: Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_general), it seems like it probably should be *General Directorate* in the U.S., which has *General Directors* and *Directorate General* in Australia, Canada, and the U.K., which all have (or had) *Directors General*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relict of the 18th c. position of France as a world power and French as the lingua franca of European royalty and diplomats, many [French words](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/french-and-latin-diplomatic-terms/) dealing with government and diplomacy were either taken over directly into English:

> *attaché, chargé d’affaire, communiqué, détente, rapprochement*

or adapted, preserving postpositive adjective word order:

> *secretary general,  ambassador extraordinary, ambassador plenipotentiary*

USAmerican passports still contain [French translations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_passport#Languages) of some text, with Spanish appearing during the second Clinton administration as a nod to Puerto Rico, whose residents are American citizens but without the right to vote on the island, though they may do so if they become permanent residents of one of the 50 states.

The [Directorates-General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directorate-General) of the European Union, headed by directors-general — both with hyphen — follow this naming convention.

Comment: l totally agree with your clear  historical explanation, but l want to know what the Americans and  the British usually use,  the Directorate General or the General Directorate.

Comment: Directorate-General/Director-General are official EU titles. My historical sketch was to show you how such usage in English is unremarkable. If you're talking, say, of a business firm and not the EU, then it's a general director.